# Putting an "OR" in Xero-API queries

Tags: xero-api

I'd like to expand the search functionality so that users can enter in some text and have that matched against multiple fields eg name and email

How do I specify that in the "where" string?

```
if (!is_null($output['search']['value'])) {
   $where .= '&&' . 'Name.ToLower().Contains("' . strtolower($output['search']['value']) . '")';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the word `OR` - e.g.

```
?where=Name.Contains("contactname")+OR+(EmailAddress+!=+null+AND+EmailAddress.Contains("contactemail"))
```

As per [the docs](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/requests-and-responses) though, complex `where` clauses are bad for performance. I'd strongly recommend making separate requests for each property where possible.

Comment: Thanks @rustyskates

Twigged when looking through the invoices that maybe I was passing raw code rather than parameters that were going to be manipulated. The paging is pretty primitive too so I might change my approach.